# Seeking Solutions for Site Inaccessibility After Deleting Apache's ProxyPass Configuration

Tags: apache, centos, vps, proxypass, conf.d

I was adjusting my Apache server settings today but accidentally deleted `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ProxyPass`. After this change, I can no longer access `https://domain`, and all related subdomain sites have also become inaccessible.

`ProxyPass` is a directive in Apache configuration that redirects specific requests to another server or application. Deleting it seems to have caused the site to become inaccessible. Before deleting the configuration file, the site was functioning normally, so I believe there are no issues with other configuration files (such as `ssl.conf`).

**What I Researched:**

- The `ProxyPass` directive is a standard feature in Apache server and cannot be downloaded separately.
- Restoring the `ProxyPass` settings can be difficult without a backup as it's server-specific.
- I checked Apache's official documentation and forums but only found specific examples of `ProxyPass` settings.
  [Apache mod_proxy Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

**What I Tried:**

- I thought reinstalling `httpd` might also restore `ProxyPass`.

```bash
  yum remove httpd
  yum install httpd

 Package                       Architecture      Version                    Repository            Size
=======================================================================================================
Installing:
 httpd                         x86_64            2.4.57-5.el9               appstream             47 k
Installing dependencies:
 centos-logos-httpd            noarch            90.4-1.el9                 appstream            252 k
Installing weak dependencies:
 mod_http2                     x86_64            1.15.19-5.el9              appstream            149 k
 mod_lua                       x86_64            2.4.57-5.el9               appstream             61 k
```

**My Issues:**

I've never dealt with ProxyPass before, and I'm unsure if it was part of the original files.
I'm unclear about the correct way to reset the specific ProxyPass settings.
I don't have a server backup to refer to for the original settings.
Any guidance or advice on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I checked `/var/log/httpd/error-log` and found port 3000 error. So I fixed the config file that is related to the port.

It works as before.